# shape fitting - gis

Tags: gis

Let us say I have two shapes. One is a polygon and the other a square. Each shape consists of lines which two points (a latitude/logitude pair). I would like to determine the degree to which the square is within the polygon (percentages 0 ... 100). Is this possible? Any pointers to relevant algorithms would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you could try [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). or [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/)

Found CGAL in the [intersection detection](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/intersection-detection.shtml) section of the [Stonybrook Algorithm Repository](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/) maintained by [Steven Skiena](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/) and GEOS on [OpenGeo](http://www.osgeo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the projection, add the data to a Postgis/postgres table, compute the area, and then do a matrix between all your boxes such that the data is area_box_1 / area_box_2

```
Boxes    |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5
    1       20%   0%   0%     5%    0%
    ----------------------------------
    2
    ----------------------------------
    3
    ----------------------------------
    4
    ----------------------------------
    5
```